# HTMLAgilityPack How to parse a specific attribute in HTML Contents

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Can anyone please help me how to parse a specific attribute (if I understand right). the below is a sample.

```html
<div class="buy-container">
<form action="/content/action" method="post">
<button class="product-buy">buy</button>
<input type="hidden" name="ActionAddToBasket">
<input type="hidden" value="198300" name="ContentNodeID">
<input type="hidden" value="778768" name="ContentObjectID">
<input type="hidden" value="full" name="ViewMode">
</form>
</div>
```

I would like to parse where value = "778768" from the above html data.
Please advice. Many thanks.

Comment: How is the above data presented/created? I'm thinking String.IndexOf("\"778768\"") but maybe I'm not seeing something?

Comment: What is the required result of this parse operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
  var val = doc
              .DocumentNode
              .SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='ContentObjectID']")
              .Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Check this [fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n9OSCR)

Comment: Many Many Thanks Hari for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html = @"
<div class=""buy-container"">
<form action=""/content/action"" method=""post"">
<button class=""product-buy"">buy</button>
<input type=""hidden"" name=""ActionAddToBasket"">
<input type=""hidden"" value=""198300"" name=""ContentNodeID"">
<input type=""hidden"" value=""778768"" name=""ContentObjectID"">
<input type=""hidden"" value=""full"" name=""ViewMode"">
</form>
</div>
";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var input = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name = 'ContentObjectID']");

// your desired value
var val = input.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
```